# getting started with rails guide: how do you create the files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the getting started with rails guide and i am stuck at a certain point. I am up to creating a new html.erb file within the app/views/articles. However how do i actually create the new file. Do u do it in the command prompt or another script editor?

Comment: You just create a file. There is no philosophy here. Most systems will allow you to do it with GUI, right click within the folder -> new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any way you like really. You can do it in command prompt if you are more comfortable with it or you can create it in script editor.